# How to set a breakpoint in a shared library opened with dlopen in QTCreator in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am trying to debug with QTCreator my shared library which is being called with dlopen and dlsym.
QT debugger does not stop at breakpoints in the shared library.

When I run my app with with GDB it works correctly.

The SO has debugging symbols.

how can I get QTCreator to debug my app?

Thanks.

Update:

I created a gdb startup script with the full path to my project and it now works.
Thing is, I don't want this script to run for every project using QT.

Is it possible to do this per project?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same exact problem. Could you share more details regarding your solution? Have you found the "proper" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GDB is unable to locate your .so file. You should check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31164313/3336423) to see if the shared library can be found in your `solib-search-path`. If it's not, you should extend the "Additional Startup Commands" field in Tools/Options/Debugger/GDB with something like:

```
set solib-search-path %{CurrentProject:BuildPath}/<relative path to the folder where the .so file was built>
```

In my situation, working under Android, I set `set solib-search-path %{CurrentProject:BuildPath}/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a` and now breakpoints work if set in shared libraries code.

@ChrisF: Tried to mark [Debugging a dynamically-loaded library in c++ with QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35491190/3336423) as being a duplicate of this question, but I must wait to have an upvote (stackoverflow won't let me flag the duplicate because "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"..."